# Unable to deploy image to kubernetes (Problems with packaging structure)

Tags: typescript, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

On successfully building using below dockerfile, I am unable to deploy my application on eks.

```js
FROM node:12
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY udagram-feed/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci 
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

on fetching logs from cluster, this is what i get:

```js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/www/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! udagram-user@1.0.0 prod: `tsc && node ./www/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the udagram-user@1.0.0 prod script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-20T19_11_45_220Z-debug.log
```

running the image locally, i have the below file structure:

- Dockerfile
- node_modules
- package.json
- package-lock.json
- src

the src/ directory contains the serves.ts sequelize.ts and other files. Clearly there is no www/ directory. Why is kubernetes looking for files in this directory?
Any help is appreciated. I have been stuck on this for days now, don't know what to do.
For file structure, please see the github repo [Github](https://github.com/Pranjal-sopho/udagram)

Comment: Can you `docker run` the same image outside of Kubernetes?  (Do _not_ use `-v` options to overwrite the code in the image.)  You `COPY` the `package.json` file from a `udagram-feed` subdirectory; do you need to `COPY` the application code from that subdirectory too?

Answer (score 0):

First, your Dockerfile created a 1GB image. I modified it to create a 240MB image. This Dockerfile can be further optimized; you can refer [here](https://gist.github.com/hdhruna/857fa1646438a05bd758823604360509) and [here](https://gist.github.com/hdhruna/53a913d72eba2be67b569fe5da39860d) for examples on creating a multi-stage Dockerfile.:

```
FROM node:12-alpine 
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .gyp \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
    && npm ci \
    && apk del .gyp
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

Here's the docker image sizes:

```
REPOSITORY                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
udagram-feed-alpine                 latest              185478b5eabc        11 seconds ago      247MB
udagram-feed                        latest              fbf32e67d4fa        4 minutes ago       1.07GB
```

Secondly, your [package.json](https://github.com/Pranjal-sopho/udagram/blob/master/udagram-feed/package.json#L10) is referring to `./www/server.js` file

Comment: so what if i chage the last line to CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ] or change "prod" value in package.json ?

Comment: Yes, changing to `CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]` and/or `prod` in your package.json should work.

Comment: Now I am unable to build using the new dockerfile provided. "no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/app/package.json'" is the error now. @hdhruna

Comment: From your [COPY](https://github.com/Pranjal-sopho/udagram/blob/master/udagram-feed/Dockerfile#L7) command, remove `udagram-feed/`